# How to implement a live search for multiple text fields inside one column of a table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have currently implemented a live search (search as you type) function on text fields. The flow is something like this.

1. Call a .js file inside the page.
2. Set the id of the text field to "client-search".
3. Inside the .js file it is currently listening for on key up events of the "client-search" text field.
4. If the on key up event is fired, the .js file calls a PHP file that searches the database and returns the output as a list item in an unordered list underneath the "client-search" text field.

This setup currently works but how do implement it in multiple fields inside a single page, since it works using "id" and obviously I can't have multiple IDs in a single page.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="client-search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for manager...">
<ul class="livesearch" id="client-result" onclick="clickResult()"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready
$j(document).ready(function() {  

// Icon Click Focus
$j('div.icon').click(function(){
    $j('input#client-search').focus();
});

// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#client-search').val();
    $j('b#search-string').text(query_value);
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "clientsearch.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#client-result").html(html);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}

$j("input#client-search").live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $j("ul#client-result").fadeOut();
    }else{
        $j("ul#client-result").fadeIn();
        $j(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$serverName = "(local)";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CMS");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {

} else {
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$html = '';
$html .= '<li value="myLi" class="myLi">';
$html .= '<small>nameString</small>';
$html .= '<small></small>';
$html .= '</li>';

$search_string = $_POST['query'];
//$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);

if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

$sql = "SELECT TOP 10 ClientName FROM Client WHERE ClientName LIKE '%" . $search_string . "%'";

$params = array($search_string);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $results_array[] = $row;
}

if (isset($results_array)) {
    foreach ($results_array as $result) {

        $display_function = $result['ClientName'];
        $display_name = $result['ClientName'];

        $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

        //$output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

        echo($output);
    }
}else{
    $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $html);
    $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

    echo($output);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Please share your code-@iamlawrencev

Comment: how about using a class instead of an id? and what's the difference between `$` and `$j`? since both seem to reference jQuery.